# Sending a BroadcastReceiver intent to a service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

Typically you start a service like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,MessageService.class);
context.startService(i);
```

but what I want to do is send an intent that was received in a `BroadcastReceiver` to a service. If I start a service the way shown above that wont get the intent from the `BroadcastReceiver` correct?

Basically I just want my `BroadcastReceiver` to start my service and then let the service itself handle what kind of intent was received

is this possible?

Comment: I assume that you're asking if you can pass the same Intent you received in BR to starte the Service, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send Intent from BroadcastReceiver to Service as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MessageService.class);
String value = "String you want to pass";
String name = "data";
intent.putExtra(name, value);
context.startService(intent);
```

Reciver Intent in `onStartCommand` method of service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (intent.getStringExtra("data") != null) {
     {
       String str=intent.getStringExtra("data");//get data here sended from BroadcastReceiver 
     }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}
```

for how we communicate between Service and BroadcastReceiver see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420495/sending-an-intent-from-broadcast-receiver-to-a-running-service-in-android)

Comment: I think `Intent intent` should be `Intent intent2open` for your code to compile. Am I right?