# Have BroadcastReceiver run as Service in the background + Auto Start after boot

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm very new to Android and Programming in general, so I'm playing around with different
tutorials and info gathered here on stackoverflow.

What I would like to accomplish, is having the app with my SMS BroadcastReceiver run as a service, so I can get all the SMS broadcasts when app is in the background.

Also, how can I add a BroadcastReceiver for receiving broadcast of BOOT_COMPLETED and start app automatically?

Would I need several services for this, or is 1 service sufficient? (for detecting SMS + BOOT_COMPLETED continuously)

Currently I have a created a BroadcastReceiver for getting SMS, like this;

```
public class SMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   .. etc ..
   .. etc ..
}
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml file has receiver and intent-filter with the 
additional `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`

Getting the SMS broadcast works fine, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

All help is much appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: You know that in Android, a "Service" is *not* the same as a "Service" in Windows, right? Running a Service constantly costs battery. Maybe what you want is an IntentService, that stops itself after handling all pending Intents sent to it (for example by your broadcast receiver).

Comment: Yes, if I understand the concept correctly, it will consume battery.

But I'm looking for solution as of how to continuously get the SMS from the BroadcastReceiver. :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, the System will call your BroadCastReceiver. No Service needed. Please someone correct me or confirm this, since I am not 100% sure any more.

Comment: So it doesn't need to be started by a Service to run continuously? If so, that would be great. But I've seen other BroadCastReceivers, like for the BOOT_COMPLETED and incoming/outgoing phone numbers, they all were run by services?

Comment: The thing is: you can register a receiver dynamically or through the manifest. Depends on the desired behaviour. For example if you want to receive broadcast on wifi connectivity in your App, you will register for it in onResume and deregister in onPause. In other cases it might be sensible to have a service do that to be able to receive while the app is in background ...

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421600/982149

Comment: It's registered in the Manifest as of now. Could I f.ex register and unregister the BroadcastReceivers dynamically in the Service with onCreate() / onDestroy() ? How would I go about to do that

Comment: The [docu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) has some good explanations for all this. Read, try, come back and update the question :)

Comment: Danke sehr, Fildor. I will read up some more and try to figure it out. All I want is to detect SMS at ALL times, even when phone is asleep, so probably not an easy task for a newbie :)

Comment: That's true. I wouldn't have a solution out of the box, either. Good luck.

Comment: @user2354810 if (android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action)) this line throw error for me,android.intent cannot be resolved why this error coming

Answer (score 1):

To start your service on BOOT_COMPLETED event and to receive SMS intent continuously.

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<receiver android:name="BootReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**BootReceiver.java**:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, SMSService.class);
        context.startService(service);
  }
}
```

**SMSService.java**:

```
public class SMSService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         String action = intent.getAction();
         if (Intent.BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action)) {
             //write your code to process BOOT_COMPLETED intent here
         }
         else if(Intent.SMS_RECEIVED.equals(action)) {
             //Write your code for processing SMS intent here
         }
    }
}
```

As, [Fildor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982149/fildor) has pointed out, it is unnecessary to start service on BOOT_COMPLETED intent. InentService would do the work. So, above two code snippets are not required. Just the last snippet would do the work.

Comment: That would be awesome. You mean that I dont need to instantiate any BroadcastReceivers or Services at all, just use IntentService for both BOOT_COMPLETED and SMS_RECEIVED ? (Btw, does IntentService show up as a running service?) 

Thanks for all help, will try it out and let you know how it worked for me :)

Comment: if (android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action)) this line throw error for me,android.intent cannot be resolved why this error coming @mopurizwarriors

Comment: if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) this code is useful if anyone got error

Comment: @mopurizwarriors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374238/after-rebooting-my-device-sending-sms-frequently-is-sending-sms-one-more-time-al could you see this one